# 'Bad request' (400) error with WordPress Ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I don't understand why I get a 400 'bad request' error with the Ajax code below. I don't get any Apache error btw:

PHP (functions.php)

```
function load_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');  
  wp_enqueue_script('main_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/scripts/main.js', array('jquery'), true);
  wp_localize_script('main_js', 'WPaAjax', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');

function send_message_function() {
  echo 'YES!';
  exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_send_message', 'send_message_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_send_message', 'send_message_function');
```

JS (main.js)

```
$('.contact_form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $(this).serializeArray();
  $.post(WPaAjax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    $('body').append(response);
  });
});
```

Comment: what is in your `data`( from js. )? but the problem is with it. you're serializing it, and wordpress can't get the `action` for it

Comment: Works now, thanks! If you make an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: glad to help. accept the answer of @cabrerahector as right. it's more detailed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Bad Request` error message you're seeing is because WordPress considers your request -wait for it- invalid:

1. You're passing an array of objects to [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) when it expects a plain object or a string. You want to use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) instead:

   ```
   $('.contact_form').submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);
     $.post(WPaAjax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
       $('body').append(response);
     });
   });
   ```

and:

2. WordPress expects the `action` parameter to be included with your request, which seems to be missing from your code. So:

   ```
   $('.contact_form').submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);
     data.append("action", "send_message");
     $.post(WPaAjax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
       $('body').append(response);
     });
   });
   ```

Comment: Sorry, I missed the comment the OP left in his question asking Samvel to post an answer so he could accept it. @drake035 please feel free to accept Samvel's answer instead of mine if he does leave one.